# VMWare: Redirect linux console beep to sound card

Tags: windows-7, linux, vmware, console

I'm sitting in a large office of 20 people or so. I - as others - have headphones, so we do not disturb each other. The problem is that when my guest Linux beeps it "appears" on my laptop's internal speaker. I have found thousands of ways on the net about how to disable the beeping. I don't want that, I do like it, it brings useful information to me.

Instead, I would like to have it redirected / converted to my sound card, so I would be able to hear it via my headphones.

- VMware Workstation 7.1.1 build-282343
- Host: Windows 7 Enterprise, version 6.1 (build 7601, Service Pack 1)
- Guest: Debian Squeeze, Linux 2.6.32, vmware-tools installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Fancy Beeper Daemon](http://www.carcosa.net/jason/software/beep/). I never tested it, but I stumbled on that problem of weeks ago.
Note that this a Linux kernel module and that you will have to install it on every guest you manage under VMware for this to work.

Another solution I found (but didn't try) for VMware Workstation was to add a soundcard to the guest OS, that way system beeps *should* be redirected to your physical soundcard. Let us now if that works if you do try!

Comment: url is broken now (2023-06-03) :/

Answer (score 0):

if you're ok with redirecting *all* guest audio to your headphones, you can do that under Virtual Machine Settings -> Hardware -> Sound Card -> Connection -> Specify host sound card
[image]